# Image of the matrix and its rref

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a matrix $A$. Is $ \mathrm{image}(A) $ equal to $ \mathrm{image}(\mathrm{rref}(A)) $? Their kernels and solution of the system $ Ax = b $ is the same.

Comment: The image is the span of the columns, i believe. Row operations preserve the dimension of the image but the resulting rows do not necessarily span the image.

Comment: Yes. It's easy to see this by showing that (separately) each of the three basic row operations preserves the image, since reducing to RREF can be achieved by stringing together those operations appropriately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Here is an example:
Let A be 
$\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1\\
1 & 1\\
\end{array} \right)$.

Then rref(A)=$\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1\\
0 & 0\\
\end{array} \right)$.

Column space of A is $span\left\{\left( \begin{array}{c}
1\\
1\\
\end{array} \right)\right\}$.

Column space of rref(A) is $span\left\{\left( \begin{array}{c}
1\\
0\\
\end{array} \right)\right\}$.

You are right in saying that they have the same null space (kernel).